# Function return in NodeJS module returns undefined and it's not true

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo.js module in my NodeJS application in which I try to check if document exists, if not, save to database, if yes, return error to the routes.js file which called the module function.

Here's my module:

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path'),
config = require(appRoot + '/config/config'),
db = require('mongojs').connect(config.db.host);

module.exports = {
    saveSpammer: function(ip, userAgent, fn) {
        var exist = this.find('spammers', {ip:ip, userAgent:userAgent});

        console.log(exist); // returns undefined

        if (!exist) {
            return this.save('spammers', {ip: ip, userAgent: userAgent, date: (new Date())}, fn);
        } else {
            return fn('You have already submitted a request!');
        }
    },

    save: function(col, data, fn) {
        var col = this.getCol(col);

        col.insert(data, {w:1}, function(err, records) {
            if (err) {
                return fn(err);
            } else {
                return fn(null, records);
            }
        });
    },

    find: function(col, query, fn) {
        var col = this.getCol(col);

        col.find(query, function(err, docs) {
            console.log(docs); // returns list of documents from mongo
            console.log(docs ? 1 : 0); // returns 1

            if (docs) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I output "docs" variable in find functions, i see correct data, then based on it i return true or false based on the existence of a document, the problem is that return from a function find to function saveSpammer gives me "undefined".

I am using a regular function return as in JavaScript, maybe I am missing something in the concept of NodeJS?

Please assist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your example is that the `col.find()` call executes asynchronously.

So

```
var exist = this.find('spammers', {ip:ip, userAgent:userAgent});
console.log(exist); // returns undefined
```

is the expected behavior since `this.find` does not return anything. You can see that there is no `return` in the definition of the `find` function.

You need to use the callback mechanism

```
this.find('spammers', {ip:ip, userAgent:userAgent}, function(err, exist) {
    console.log(exist);
    .. rest of the code here
});
```

and modify the `find` function with

```
if (err) {
    fn(err);
} else if (docs) {
    fn(null, true);
} else {
    fn(null, false);
}
```